# Retrieve RDS DB identifiers (DB names) from AWS CLI in Terraform

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm facing a tricky issue: I would like to retrieve all the RDS DB identifiers (DB names) using the AWS CLI (but with a specific tag !), to then use the outputs in Terraform. But i'm able to get only the ARNs so a second part would be to extract DBs names that are at the end of each ARNs.

Using this command:

```
aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources --resource-type-filters rds:db --tag-filters Key=MyKey,Values=MyValue --query 'ResourceTagMappingList[*].{ARN: ResourceARN}'
```

I'm able to have this:

```
[
    {
        "ARN": "arn:aws:rds:eu-west-1:99999999999:db:my-db-name"
    },
    {
        "ARN": "arn:aws:rds:eu-west-1:99999999999:db:my-db-name-2"
    }
]
```

or just a list with this command:

```
aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources --resource-type-filters rds:db --tag-filters Key=MyKey,Values=MyValue --query 'ResourceTagMappingList[*].ResourceARN'
```

```
[
    "arn:aws:rds:eu-west-1:99999999999:db:my-db-name",
    "arn:aws:rds:eu-west-1:99999999999:db:my-db-name-2"
]
```

I tried severals stuff like:

```
data "external" "json" {
  program = ["sh", "-c", "aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources --resource-type-filters rds:db --tag-filters Key=MyKey,Values=MyValue --query 'ResourceTagMappingList[*].{ARN: ResourceARN}'"]
}

output "external" {
  value = data.external.json
}
```

But i'm facing json errors like:

```
Result Error: json: cannot unmarshal array into Go value of type map[string]string
```

It looks like json parsing of external data source is a bit tricky and I don't have much experience in bash and terraform. So i'm not able to retrieve the values in terraform and I also don't know where it's the best to cut ARNs, in the bash command or in terraform ? For example I would need to extract `my-db-name` & `my-db-name-2` from the ARNs.

Thanks

Comment: Follow this approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/73819244/3390419

Comment: Why can you not use https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/db_instance?

Comment: @Paolo @Paolo, I Yes I have already tried several stuff like that using jq: `["bash", "-c", "aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources --resource-type-filters rds:db --tag-filters Key=MyKey,Values=MyValue | jq -r '.ResourceTagMappingList | map({'key': \"arn\", 'value': .ResourceARN})'"]`. I’m ending up with a nice json when running the command in local. But still in terraform I got the error `json: cannot unmarshal array into Go value of type map[string]string`

Comment: @MattSchuchard Unfortunately this isn't working in my case because this data source can't retrieve the DBs by tags, only with the identifier. That's why i'm using aws cli where there is an option to get all the DBs that have a specific tag.